# How to translate Language in android?

Tags: android, localization

I want to translate language into another language but the Google API was shut off. Is there any alternative way to translate the language??

Comment: I used Apertium API also but there is an exception for Error retrieving Translation.

Comment: What do you mean by "translate language"? Translate any user input?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this app: http://www.pedrorainho.eu/applications/apktranslator

It was done by me to translate my android apps, and uses bing

Answer (score 0):

If you mean embedding machine translation in your page, it’s still possible using Google services, either width the paid service Google Translate API v2 or using [Google Website Translator](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) suitably. Regarding the latter, see the simple demo page
http://www.bytelevelbooks.com/code/javascript/transinput.html
(about translating user input). There’s a discussion of the topic in my book [Going Global with JavaScript and Globalize.js](http://www.bytelevelbooks.com/books/global_javascript.html), with some notes on the alternatives and pitfalls. Generally, automatic translation may work reasonably for sentences of very simple grammatical structure, so it might be feasible a) for generated texts planned to be translatable that way, b) for user input in situations where the user knows the target language somewhat (e.g., reads reasonably but writes poorly), so that he has some chances of checking that the translations make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Bing API at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877832.aspx